# Find record less than or equals 0 but no repeat record

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, 1 first look this:
Table state_inventary

```
ID_STATE_INVENTARY,   DESCRIPTION
0                     STORE
1                     TRANSIT
2                     SOLD_STORE
3                     STORAGE
```

Table article_stock

```
ID_STOCK ID_ORIGIN ARTICLE UNIT_SOLD ID_STATE_INVENTARY
0        1         A       10        0
1        2         A       0         1
2        1         B       5         2
3        3         C       0         3
4        4         D       0         3
5        5         E       10        1
6        2         A       0         2
7        1         B       0         2
```

I need to find articles with ID_STATE_INVENTORY with value 0 or 2 or 3, I get it
But I need to find articles with the UNIT_SOLD the sum is zero, I don't know how do these
I want to find somthing like that

```
ID_STOCK ID_ORIGIN ARTICLE UNIT_SOLD ID_STATE_INVENTARY
3        3         C       0         3
4        4         D       0         3
```

OR

```
ARTICLE
C
D
```

In my query I have next result

```
ID_STOCK ID_ORIGIN ARTICLE UNIT_SOLD ID_STATE_INVENTARY
1        2         A       0         1
3        3         C       0         3
4        4         D       0         3
6        2         A       0         2
7        1         B       0         2
```

Anyone idea how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```sql
SELECT SUM(`UNIT_SOLD`) AS `UNIT_SOLD`, `ARTICLE` FROM `table_name` GROUP BY `ARTICLE`;
```